# Apple Script put clipboard list in quotes

Tags: applescript, clipboard, transformation

Does anyone know of an applescript that will take whatever is on the clipboard and wrap it in quotes. (Ideally triggered by key shortcut, but i can set that up myself)

Example (Copied Data from excel col)

```
Beer
Whisky
Chronic
```

Would turn into

```
'Beer','Whisky','Chronic'
```

I can't find this anywhere and I can only do some basic stuff in Applescript but I totally think it would help a lot of devs/db admins!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the source is plain text and the items are separated by newline characters
you can do it with `text item delimiters`

```
set theText to "Beer
Whisky
Chronic"

set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, {linefeed, return}}
set theList to text items of theText
set text item delimiters to "','"
set theResult to "'" & (theList as text) & "'"
set text item delimiters to TID
theResult
```

To get the data directly from the clipboard replace the first line with

```
set theText to the clipboard
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @vadian for the help there - the final working script
takes input from clipboard, transforms and then puts back to clipboard

```
set theText to (do shell script "pbpaste")
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, {linefeed, return}}
set theList to text items of theText
set text item delimiters to "','"
set theResult to "'" & (theList as text) & "'"
set text item delimiters to TID
set the clipboard to theResult
theResult
```

I've set it up as a service using automator and assigned a keyboard shortcut for quick transform.